# Install a dedicated Fedora on USB key

Tags: usb, fedora, liveusb

I'd like to install Fedora on my USB key, not the LiveCD one but a real installation, with my username, encrypted disk, updates & configuration saved between reboot, etc.

I'd like to install it on the USB to take advantages of the speed, instead off the hard drive, like using my USB key as a SSD.

My USB key is a 16Go, I think to split it in two distincts uses : 10Go for Fedora (with all partitions (/ & swap) encrypted) and 6Go for the data (NTFS, because it will be connected to Windows too).

I searched if this was possible. There is Pungi and Revisor that could do the trick, but I can't see how I can set the partitions, session name, encrypting the partitions, etc.

I thought about running a LiveCD on my computer, with the USB key plugged in, and then install Fedora on the key, but I don't know if it's possible.

Could you help me please?

Thanks :)

Comment: Just as a note, if you plan to put /home on NTFS...that will yield interesting side-effects...including broken permissions and software refusing to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your premise is flawed, most USB keys are not faster than HDDs. SSDs are fast because they use an array of memory cells which can be accessed in parallel.

However if you want to do this for portability reasons then looky here: http://hak5.org/episodes/haktip-4

Comment: `...most USB keys are not faster than HDDs.` Citation needed. USB-Devices have the upside of a heavily reduced access time (like SSDs). That makes them faster if you have to access a lot of files...like when an OS is loading.

Comment: For me it was just an observation : I booted on a LiveUsb and it was ready faster than a clean install on my drive.

Comment: Can I choose to encrypt the partitions where Linux will be installed via YUMI?